# SQL program changing my code

Tags: sql-server

Is there something wrong with the code:

```
SELECT Konta.ID, Konta.Okres, Konta.Symbol, Konta.Nazwa
FROM ep15_opisie.dbo.Konta Konta
WHERE (LEN(Konta.Symbol)='5') AND (((Konta.Symbol Like '%221%') OR (Konta.Symbol Like '%222%') OR (Konta.Symbol Like '%302%') OR (Konta.Symbol Like '%700%'))
```

But the program I'm using (Microsoft Query) changes the code to:

```
SELECT Konta.ID, Konta.Okres, Konta.Symbol, Konta.Nazwa
FROM ep15_opisie.dbo.Konta Konta
WHERE (Konta.Symbol Like '%221%') AND (LEN(Konta.Symbol)='5') OR (Konta.Symbol Like '%222%') AND (LEN(Konta.Symbol)='5') OR (Konta.Symbol Like '%302%') AND (LEN(Konta.Symbol)='5') OR (Konta.Symbol Like '%700%') AND (LEN(Konta.Symbol)='5')
```

It multiplies the LEN argument. It doesn't make sense to me, since I want all the arguemnts to have a LEN of 5, but with different Like 'XXX'). I'm using SQL Server.

What is the best method to use only one LEN argument?

Comment: Just asking...are the results from the two queries not similar? Because the program is producing a logically equivalent query...you wanted A AND (B or C or D) ; it opened the brackets and gave you (A and  B) or (A and C) or (A and D) and A .

Comment: Bear in mind that, unlike more procedural languages, there's no guaranteed evaluation order of conditions or of how many times identical clauses will be evaluated (provided that they're deterministic). The two queries are identical, logically, and the optimizer should produce identical plans for either one. (Also, if this is the query or view wizard changing your code around, the simple answer is to stop using the visual designers and just use plain query windows - they won't rearrange your code)

Comment: Yes, the results of the query are the same. What I want to do is reduce the lenght of the code. What if I wanted to include a third condition? With every condition added, the lenght of the code would explode.

Comment: So *stop* using the visual design tools. Just write your queries in a query window. Those windows *don't* rewrite your code. Whereas a visual designer has to rip apart your query and then, from the ripped apart form, construct valid SQL - it's aiming for "dumb but correct" rather than trying to write concise code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the parser is **logically** right. Anyway, what about trying to write something like this. I think performances likely remain unchanged.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Konta.ID
        ,Konta.Okres
        ,Konta.Symbol
        ,Konta.Nazwa
    FROM ep15_opisie.dbo.Konta Konta
    WHERE (
            (
                (Konta.Symbol LIKE '%221%')
                OR (Konta.Symbol LIKE '%222%')
                OR (Konta.Symbol LIKE '%302%')
                OR (Konta.Symbol LIKE '%700%')
                )
            )
    ) Konta
WHERE (LEN(Konta.Symbol) = '5')
```